# "Missing LSB tags and overrides" error on /etc/init.d script

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I made a script as showed in this tutorial:
http://edv-huber.com/index.php/problemloesungen/15-custom-splash-screen-for-raspberry-pi-raspbian

But after executing a command:

```
insserv /etc/init.d/asplashscreen
```

I get errors:

```
insserv: warning script 'k01localhostrepair.sh missing lsb tags and overrides
insserv: warning: scrpt 'localhostrepair.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

I guess it is because I made a mistake of doing:

```
chmod 777 /etc/init.d
```

in order to copy one file there. How do I repair that and the problem above?

EDIT:
I don't know why, but it started working (not good actually). When RPi is booting, 4/5 boots end up crashing the Pi. When it is loading, there is a splash screen, but after couple seconds, so I can still see console output at the beginning. The splash image also disappears after a short time, not right before the desktop boots.

Comment: SysV-style Init scripts begin with LSB headers, which may be absent from `k01localhostrepair.sh` and `localhostrepair.sh`. LSB headers are those that start with `### BEGIN INIT INFO` and end with `### END INIT INFO`. You don't have to worry if you never edited those scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Those are just warnings, and wont actually break anything.  The idea is by providing consistent documentation inside your script about the purpose, dependancies, etc, other tools can use that.

The standard headers look like this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

Obviously, edit the specifics for your init script.

Changing the permissions on `/etc/init.d` to `777` isn't a great idea security-wise, but it alone shouldn't break the startup process.   By setting it to `777` you allow any user on the system to potentially make changes that will be run by the root user a bootup.  Better to leave those permissions at something like `755` or `775`  (see `man chmod` for more specific details on what those permissions mean)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you should probably rather look at using **"systemd"** as this is replacing "init.d" for most distro's now-a-days.

It allows for parallel compute at startup to speed things up and to avoid kernel panics from serially computed init.d processes that fail.. and a hole bunch of other things including handling dependencies mentioned.

It does seem to contain Proprietary code on scheduling side and license changes to GNU Lesser General Public License if that matters to you..

Have a look at link for more info on **systemd**
https://www.tecmint.com/systemd-replaces-init-in-linux/

and for RaspberryPi fans
https://domoticproject.com/creating-raspberry-pi-service/

Hope this helps a bit, few years late from original post .I know!

Comment: I wish there was systemd on Debian Squeeze. I happened to just need to update one box containing it... So old information is valuable too.